# « So far, so good » en français

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

Comment est-ce que je peux dire « so far, so good » en français ? « Jusqu'ici tout va bien » est la  meilleure traduction ?

Si quelqu'un ne sait pas ce que « so far, so good » signifie : c'est une expression qui veut dire « tout était bien jusqu'à présent mais à partir de maintenant peut-être ce ne sera plus bien ».

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Réponse courte : oui. « Jusqu'ici, tout va bien » correspond bien au sens général de « So far, so good » et donne la même impression de langage parlé. Dans certains contextes, on remplace parfois «va bien» par un verbe plus explicite, par exemple :

- « Jusqu'ici, c'est clair ? » (un professeur explique quelque chose)

Mais « Jusqu'ici, tout va bien » peut s'utiliser dans tous les cas, je pense.

Aussi en version interrogative : « Jusqu'ici, tout va bien ? » (« So far, so good ? »)

Et en version plus familière : « Jusqu'ici, ça va ».

Comment: « Mais l’important, c’est pas la chute. »

Comment: @Édouard Il est devenu difficile d'employer l'expression sans ironie depuis…